Razor page SiteContent data binding does not work
I have a razor page with .Net 8 core and i have set the rendermode to InteractiveServer,
@rendermode InteractiveServer

I am using the SectionContent with a variable to bind the value to the front end,
Initially the variable is set as empty string,
public string? result { get; set; } = "";

and it gets updated on click of a button as below,
result = $"Search Results for\"{Query}\"";

however, the value is not getting bound in the view.
<SectionContent SectionName="page-header-subtitle">
   @result
</SectionContent>

Can someone help?

You will have to make the outlet interactive:
<SectionOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" SectionName="page-header-subtitle" />


No that also did not render the result, am I missing something?

btw where is result in your sample code?

also what is sectionOutlet?

It works on my PC.  Surely you have a SectionOutlet somewhere?  I put this one in MainLayout.razor.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0#blazor-sections

To expand on Henk's answer with Interactivity set to per page/component.
What are you doing different?
MainLayout:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Sections
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>
        <SectionOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" SectionName="page-header-subtitle" />
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

Counter
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Sections
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<SectionContent SectionName="page-header-subtitle">
    <div class="m-2">
        @currentCount
    </div>
</SectionContent>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}


